# CSS within a Div tag

Tags: html, css, doctype

[W3C Css Validator for my CSS file](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://www.killgorack.com/killgorack.com%25202.0/&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=)

[The HTML here](http://www.killgorack.com/killgorack.com%202.0/)

My question is that when I put some CSS inside of a DIV tag it stops working when I go to doctype 4.01 from 4.0 (transitional) The goal here of course to have all the bells and whistles working in the latest version of IE, FF, and Chrome. What am I missing here?

I've searched this site but can't find anything that can help yet.. Hopes it's something simple..

```
<div class="ContentContainer"><div class="text1">Formatting for text1 is NOT working.</div></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: tell us what does not work ... we cannot read minds ;)

Comment: What specifically stops working?  Which `div`?  What `CSS`?  "bells & whistles"?  Please post the relevant code within your question and explain what it does and what you expect it to do.  Read http://sscce.org and post the bare minimum code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: [Fix your invalid HTML too](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.killgorack.com%2Fkillgorack.com%25202.0%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Various "unclosed elements" which may or may not be caused by your invalid comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the html5 doctype ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

---

you also seem to be using a wrong html comment syntax ..

comments should be like `<!-- Menu here -->` (*[documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4)*) and ***not*** like `<! Menu here ===========>`

---

**Update**

CSS is case sensitive, so when you apply a class of `text1` it will not match a CSS rule named `Text1`

Comment: Just changed it and no dice.. Tried that earlier also.. anything else?

Comment: added another issue that stands out.. other than that please read the comment of @sparky and give a more detailed description of the problem..

Comment: @DavidMonroe, also looks like these invalid comments may or may not be triggering a bunch of "unclosed element" errors.  Please fix your question before it gets closed.

Comment: Of course you're correct. anything within <div class="ContentContainer"><div class="text1">Formatting for text1 is NOT working.</div></div>

Comment: @DavidMonroe, updated answer.. CSS is case sensitive.. so `text1` is not the same as `Text1`

Comment: @Gaby Changed the case sensitive issue, thanks! but still the formatting is not coming through.

Comment: Again, @DavidMonroe, can you _please_ fix your question?

Comment: @gaby fixed the comment errors also thanks for that one.

Comment: yep... CSS rules applied as classes need to start with `.` in the CSS. `.text1{..}` A rule that is in the CSS as just `text1` refers to a tag `<text1>blah blah</text1>`

Comment: @Gaby Wonderfull! that did it.. now I gotta fix errors with the changing of the doctype.

Comment: @Sparky, not sure what question you're referring to!

Comment: @DavidMonroe, _this one_ => [CSS within a Div tag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13898425/594235)

Comment: @sparky, sorry but what do I need to fix?!

Comment: @DavidMonroe, Seriously?  Just read my first comment underneath your original question.

Comment: This is a minor point, but as I understand it CSS by itself is *not* case sensitive. [Read about it in the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#casesens). I think it's the HTML that adds in case sensitivity with classes and ids.

Comment: @jmeas, interesting.. I thing though that it refers to CSS specific selectors, and i mean that CSS keywords like `first-child`, `nth-child`, `:before` etc.. are case insensitive.. Class names relate to attribute values which are document language dependent. [***example***](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bTMCv/1/)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, right, that's what I was trying to say. I just did so less elegantly :)